# bank account assignment

Tags: java

I'm trying to make bank pattern grid by using blue color but I could't fix the side. Can someone see my code and help me to fix the side?

```
int h = grid.getHt();  
int w = grid.getWd();

for (int row = 0; row < (w/2)+1; row++) 
    for (int col = 0; col < row+2; col++){ 
         grid.setColor(row, col, Color.BLUE); 
         grid.setColor(w - row, col, Color.BLUE); 
    }
```

my code print out

$

$$

$$$

$$$$

$$$$$

$$$$$$

$$$$$

$$$$

$$$

$$

$

what i want

```
    $

   $ $

  $ $ $

$ $ $ $ $
```

$--assume blue color

Answer (score 1):

This should be usefull for you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

What you'll have to do first is figure out what's the maximum length you'll need for the last line. And add the spaces based on that.

```
(maxLength - charsInLine) / 2
```

This will be the amount of spaces before/after the printed $ ( Or something like that )